set the value of Column B based on the value in the column name that corresponds to Column A value
I have an example dataframe:
columns = ["Value A_Input",  "Value B_Input", "Value C_Input", "Column A", "Column B"]
raw_data = [
    ["aaa", "ddd", "ggg", "Value A", "aaa"],
    ["bbb", "eee", "hhh", "Value C", "hhh"],
    ["ccc", "fff", "iii", "Value B", "fff"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=columns)

I want to set the value of Column B based on the value in the column name that corresponds to Column A value + string "_Input". For example, Column A first row reads "Value A", so look for Value A_Input column and find "aaa". Any hint on how to do this? Thank you
Tried the following but it doesn't work
df['Column B'] = df[str([x for x in df['Column A']]).split('_')[0]+'_Input')]


You can use pd.DataFrame.apply if speed is not of utmost importance for a succinct easy to reason approach:
import pandas as pd

columns = ["Value A_Input", "Value B_Input", "Value C_Input", "Column A", "Column B"]
raw_data = [
    ["aaa", "ddd", "ggg", "Value A", "aaa"],
    ["bbb", "eee", "hhh", "Value C", "hhh"],
    ["ccc", "fff", "iii", "Value B", "fff"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=columns)
df['Column B'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[row['Column A'] + '_Input'], axis=1)
print(df)

Output:



index
Value A_Input
Value B_Input
Value C_Input
Column A
Column B




0
aaa
ddd
ggg
Value A
aaa


1
bbb
eee
hhh
Value C
hhh


2
ccc
fff
iii
Value B
fff




We can use Numpy broadcasting to check where the columns and the values from Column A match.
m = (df['Column A'] + '_Input').to_numpy()[:, None] == df.columns.to_numpy()
df['New B'] = df.where(m).stack().reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
Value A_Input Value B_Input Value C_Input Column A Column B New B
          aaa           ddd           ggg  Value A      aaa   aaa
          bbb           eee           hhh  Value C      hhh   hhh
          ccc           fff           iii  Value B      fff   fff

